# GCD objects as Objective-C objects

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-runtime

Grand Central Dispatch objects are said to behave like Objective-C objects when compiled with an Objective-C compiler. But that's a little unclear for me.

Objective-C objects are, in fact, structures which have, at least, one field: a pointer (the `isa` pointer) to the object's class structure. The other fields, if any, correspond to the object's ivars.

So, can GCD objects be casted to structures whose first field is a pointer to an Objective-C class structure? Since dispatch objects participate in ARC, what does the compiler do: does it send `retain` and `release` messages to the objects (like `objc_msgSend(obj, @selector(retain))`, for example) or does it generate `dispatch_object_retain` and `dispatch_object_release` calls? I mean, do GCD objects respond to ObjC messages in the `[obj mesg]` fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCD objects are actual objects, and the compiler doesn't treat them specially. You can add them to Cocoa collections, po them in the debugger, etc...

However, the runtime does do a bit of special handling for them. Their isa pointer points to the dispatch vtable rather than a regular ObjC class.

Comment: But the dispatch vtable must be equivalent to a ObjC class. I mean, it must have a cache, a superclass pointer, and a structure with the class' data for introspection and message handling. Does this really happen?

Comment: What does `object_getClassName()` return if it receives a dispatch object? I could test it by myself, but I'm without my Mac this month...

Comment: It has to be equivalent enough for objc_msgSend to work, yes (since adding a branch in that for dispatch types would be much too slow)

Comment: It returns one of various OS_object classes

Comment: So, `object_getClassName((id)dispatch_get_main_queue())` returns `OS_queue`, for example? Could you confirm it for me?

Comment: And are these OS_object classes NSObject subclasses?

Comment: OS_dispatch_queue, and yes